# Subscribed component is not able to access response from observable

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe, httpservice

My component is subscribed to httpService,I am trying to store the response data coming from subscribe method in a cookie/file storage. Here, i am getting error message that `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'` when trying to access response coming from subscribe method.

```
 Cookie.set('authtoken', response.data.authToken);
```

However data is stored in cookie succesfully.

```
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

  public email;
  public password;
 constructor(public http: HttpServiceService, public toastr: ToastrService, public router: Router) { }


 public signInVerify(){    if (!this.email || !this.password) {
      this.toastr.error('Please fill all the mandatory fields')
    }
    else {
      let params = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }

      console.log('params')
      console.log(params)
      this.http.getUserSignIn(params)
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.toastr.success('User is logged in Successfully')
          console.log(response.data.authToken)
          Cookie.set('authtoken', response.data.authToken);
          Cookie.set('receiverId', response.data.userDetails.userId);
          Cookie.set('receiverName', response.data.userDetails.firstName + ' ' + response.data.userDetails.lastName);
          this.http.setLocalStorage(response.data.userDetails)

        }
        )
    }
  }
```

It could be because it does not have access to data coming in run time, but is there a way we can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your response type as `any`

```
 this.http.getUserSignIn(params)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
     // your code
 })
```

OR

You can have a custom response Interface like

```
   interface UserSignInResponse{
     data: any;
   }

   this.http.getUserSignIn(params)
        .subscribe((response: UserSignInResponse) => {
         // your code
   })
```

Note: It would be ideal to have this UserSignInResponse in other file where you can place your other interfaces as well and import this interface from there.

Comment: I tried but no luck, it is throwing syntactical error

Comment: You mean this same error `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object` you are getting ?

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object.  - I am trying to access data object which is part a response.   I am not getting any error when i access it with response['data'].

Comment: But using response['data],i am not able to access child elements of data. this issue can be solved  if i could be able to traverse to child elements eg., response[data.id]